# Clear Fragment Backstack except top fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

In my app I have some menu items in a Navigation Drawer. When the user taps one of these items and navigates to the corresponding fragment, I want the fragment backstack to be cleared EXCEPT for the fragment they just navigated to. Let me illustrate:

In my nav drawer the user has options to open fragments F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6. When the app is first opened, the user starts on F1. Let's say from F1, the user opens fragments F7 -> F8 -> F9 -> F10 using buttons within the fragment views themselves. At this point, the backstack looks like:

F1 -> F7 -> F8 -> F9 -> F10

Suppose from here, the user opens the nav drawer and selects F2. What I want to happen is that the above backstack is cleared and is populated with ONLY F2, so that they user can't go back to F10 from F2. In otherwords, the backstack should become:

Not this: F1 -> F7 -> F8 -> F9 -> F10 -> F2
But this: F2

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT 1:
One of my attempted solutions was to add an `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` to the navigationView when the activity is loading that would clear the backstack when one of the items was pressed. My solution worked, but in the process I overrode the default code that actually changes to the new fragment. I snooped through the Android API and found this:

```java
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        boolean handled = onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);
        if (handled) {
            ViewParent parent = navigationView.getParent();
            if (parent instanceof DrawerLayout) {
                ((DrawerLayout) parent).closeDrawer(navigationView);
            } else {
                BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior =
                                    findBottomSheetBehavior(navigationView);
                if (bottomSheetBehavior != null) {
                     bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                }
            }
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```

This is NOT my code. This is the native code that handles selection of menu items on the navigation drawer (found in the `NavigationUI` class). If I want to add my own `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` I would have to recreate the functionality shown above, which I can't do since some of the methods in there are protected. So that's why I don't believe this solution will work.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ianhanniballake at first I thought I would set an `OnBackStackChangedListener` to catch when one of the main fragments was opened and try to clear the backstack there, but I didn't even need to test it to realize it would close the fragment they just opened as well, which is not what I intended. Then I tried adding my own `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` to the nav bar but I didn't realise doing that would override the default action, so that just broke the sidebar entirely. Then I ran out of ideas and came here.

Comment: What do you mean "override the default action"? It would be helpful if you include the code you have right now.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I edited the question to clarify what I meant. Basically the 'default action' is that code snippet that's part of the Android API. That `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` processes the user selecting a navbar menu item into actually showing the related fragment. If I set my own `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, that functionality is overridden and no longer runs, so the fragment would never show unless I recreate that native code in my own listener.

Comment: Oh, you didn't say you were using the Navigation Component. You absolutely shouldn't be doing what you are trying to do - see the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination) that specifically say that your starting destination should be on the back stack.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Okay, so then my question becomes: how would I get rid of all the intermediate backstack entries so that it becomes just F1 -> F2?

Comment: That's what the `setupWithNavController()` methods do already. If that's not the case for you, you've probably popped your start destination off the back stack entirely (you shouldn't do that either).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clear fragments which are in backstack

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
    FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
     manager.popBackStack(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are setting all this fragment in the same activity. If yes, then it will not be very hard to achieve whatever you want to achieve.

Make sure whenever you set your fragment in suppose MainActivity, follow this code.

```
val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
if (fragment == null) {
    fragment = Frag2.newInstance()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, Frag2.TAG)
} else {
    fragmentTransaction.show(fragment)
}
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

Main logic to achieve required behaviour is behind `fragmentTransaction.replace()`.
So, whenever you set another fragment in a `container`, use `replace()` rather than `add()`.

So, try this and give me feedback about it. 
Happy coding..!

Comment: First of all, I'm using Java not Kotlin. Second, yes these fragments are all in the same activity. Third, I'm already using `replace()` every time I show a new fragment; it's not clear what exactly you're suggesting I should do.

Comment: Can you share your code in question? So, may i look it better and try to solve issue.